# Commit code into CVS in eclipse without updating on the server side

Tags: eclipse, cvs

My code in code repository CVS. I have downloaded the code to my eclipse. When I commit the changes in eclipse it did not affect the code in CVS until I write CVS update command. I think there is some code need to be added to this file in CVSROOT/loginfo. Can you assist please?

Comment: May I know how many persons are using the repository for the same project?

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities:

Some other process changed the file and Eclipse hasn't refreshed the workspace. To check, select the file in question and choose "Refresh" from the context menu. This is probably not your problem but it's a common issue, so I wanted to mention it.

Also you settings [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-19cvs-updatemerge.htm) might be worth taking a look at

If neither of those help could you give me a few more details to help you out

1. What leads you to believe that the CVSROOT/loginfo needs to be changed ?
2. Does this happen all the time and if so has it been happening forever ?
3. Exactly how are you committing your changes ? (Via the UI or command line)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Synchronize feature of Eclipse to preview what changes are waiting to be committed to the repository. Right-click on the project and select **Team** > **Synchronize**. In the Synchornize View you can see both incoming and outgoing changes and right-click on files or groups of files to update (pull from the repo) or commit them.